# I need to convert class type array to template type. Can any one help me

Tags: c++

`item[i]=static_cast<T>(the_list[i])`. This line is giving me an error stating

> [Error] invalid use of non-static data member 'SimpleVector::item'.

I think the problem is with  typecasting. Now what can I do?

```
template <class T>

class SimpleVector {

public:
    SimpleVector();
    SimpleVector(int);
    SimpleVector(const SimpleVector & copy);
    ~SimpleVector();
    friend istream &operator>>( istream &in, SimpleVector<T> &the_list) 
    {

        for(int i=0;i<the_list.size();i++)
        {

            in>>the_list[i];
            cout<<the_list[i];
            item[i]=static_cast<T>(the_list[i]);            
        }
        return in;
    }
    int size();
    T getElementAt(int n);
    T & operator[](int index);

private:

    T* item;
    int length;


};
```

```
template<typename T>

void doWork(int dataSize)
{
    SimpleVector<T> list(dataSize);
    std::cout << "Please enter the data:" << std::endl;
    cin>>list; 
    int index;  
    SimpleVector<T> s;
    cout<<"Enter the index whose values you need to retrieve\n";
    cin>>index;
    cout<<s.getElementAt(index);   
}





int main()
{

int i,choice;

cout<<"Enter the size of the array\n";
cin>>i;
cout<<"Type of data you need to enter\n";
cout<<"Press 1 for int\n";
cout<<"Press 2 for double\n";
cout<<"Press 3 for string\n";
cin>>choice;
switch(choice)
{
    case 1:
        doWork<int>(i);
        break;
    case 2:
        doWork<double>(i);
        break;
    case 3:
        doWork<string>(i);
        break;

}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: And your actual problem/question is?? There are reasons why you're not allowed to dump code only question bodies here.

Comment: Can you add details to your code? and please, reformat it

Comment: It's already a template. I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: Ah question must contain some sort of question.

Comment: item[i]=static_cast<T>(the_list[i]). Here in this line my intention is to typecast 'the_list[i]' which is an object to 'item[i]' which is of generic type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks little complicated but my guess is there is no need to use overloaded >>. Instead just make generic array in your doWork() function and pass that array to a newly created function in class. Now you can assign the array to '*item' as both are of generic type.